# How can order a list by the second char in Apache Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How can order a list by the second char?

For example this list:

```
apple
mango
orange
```

I want to be ordered by the second letter (alphabetical order)

```
mango
apple
orange
```

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate second field from the second character of the first field and then order by the second field.Finally get only the first field from the ordered relation.

```
A = LOAD 'test3.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (a1:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE a1,SUBSTRING(a1,1,2) as a2;
C = ORDER B BY a2;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE a1;
DUMP D;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: I was about to answer the same...you made it first...you can see the difference...:)

Comment: you deserve the vote...I was looking for finding the size of the string...i.e length function...I thought I need to write the UDF or what and I got this ..SIZE function... :)

Comment: No worries, I am learning too :).You might want to edit your answer for accessing the first field using $0.

Answer (score 0):

My data is

```
1,The Nightmare Before Christmas
2,The Mummy
3,Orphans of the Storm
4,The Object of Beauty

   A = LOAD '/home/abhijit/Downloads/movies.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (a1:int,a2:chararray);
   B = FOREACH A GENERATE a2,SUBSTRING(a2,1,2) as a3;
   C = ORDER B BY a3;
   D = FOREACH C GENERATE a2;
   DUMP D;
```

Comment: Ok. I have my own data here...I will paste it ...so there wont be any confusion...

Comment: @inquisitive_mind : Is this correct...Or does it need any modification...I cannot test it :(